# Subtracting two 3D patches/volumes from each other in Matlab

Tags: matlab

In my work, I have a **nonuniform** volume needs to be subtracted from my master volume/domain, and both volumes are discretized into particles, then a 3D visualization has to be constructed after the subtraction.

For a minimal example, if I have two cubes with vertices sets coordinates of

```
v1=[0 0 0;3 0 0;3 3 0;0 3 0;0 0 3;3 0 3;3 3 3;0 3 3]; % first cube
v2=[1 1 1;2 1 1;2 2 1;1 2 1;1 1 3;2 1 3;2 2 3;1 2 3]; % second cube
```

where v=[**X**,**Y**,**Z**] is the vertices 3D coordinates.

How can I subtract v2 from v1 and visualize the result?

---

P.S. I managed to create two patches as follows:

```
f1=convhulln(v1); 
p1=patch('Vertices',v1,'Faces',f1);
f2=convhulln(v2); 
p2=patch('Vertices',v2,'Faces',f2);
```

However, I couldn't figure out how to subtract them from each other.

Comment: I am afraid you first have to make clear for yourself, how your structures are defined. At this moment your `v1` and `v2` do not represent volumes. An idea would be using binary structures like `v1=ones(4,4,4)` (4x4x4 cube). Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for your input, but as I said in my question, v1 and v2 are matrices of vertices coordinates for both volumes. Using patch command and **v1** & **v2**, both volumes can be constructed. 
So, how can I subtract one patch from other?
Regards